# Angular 12 | High memory footprint | Crash page sigill error

Tags: angular, performance

Hi everyone the memory and cpu usage of my application is really high
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQjka.png) (200k-900k, sometimes 2000k)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLFmb.png)

I use the performance monitor and found that a method called "getDate" (that convert the date in a understandable format) create problem and I replace it with a Pipe; but I have still the problem.

How my cpu is so high if I'm not using the app? Where I should check?

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not enough information to help you solve your problem. The single best thing you can do when asking for coding help online is provide a short, complete example script that others can copy, paste, and run **without any modification** to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @michal.materowski Thank you for your comment, but I don't know what code I should copy, it's a general problem of my application is not a specific part of code and if it is I don't know which part. I will add some screen about the performance monitor.

Comment: Is getDate called from a template? Maybe start with posting that method and it’s call?

Comment: Yes, before was: {{this.utils.getDate(date.time)}}

Now is: {{ date.time | translocoDate }}


For the translate I use:  
  "@ngneat/transloco": "^2.23.5",
    "@ngneat/transloco-locale": "^1.4.0",

Comment: Hi added a new screen. I think that I've a lot of method called in the template (I've to check), there is a way to monitor and find what method generate so much memory?
Another question: The method in the template should impact the memory or just the cpu?

Comment: @Releow you said "it's a general problem of my application" but it seems that you know what method is causing high cpu usage. It's still hard to solve it without any context. Could you try to reproduce component that uses those packages in StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts?

Comment: @michal.materowski Because I'm sure that is causing problem but I already fixed it, I remove from all the code the method "getDate" and replace with a Pipe. Im going to reproduce to stackblitz an example

Comment: I'm happy that your problem is solved, before posting another question on stack reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Happy coding!

Comment: @michal.materowski https://stackblitz.com/edit/transloco-example-1xplvl?file=src/app/locale/locale/locale.component.ts

Comment: @michal.materowski I din't fix my problem I fix just the transloco Pipe problem, but my memory is still very high (too my cpu) LOL

Comment: Maybe you have high cpu usage because of the angular change detection. Install the angular chrome devtools extension for chrome.  Then you can use the profiler tab, which shows you the individual change detection cycles. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-devtools/ienfalfjdbdpebioblfackkekamfmbnh

Comment: @JanMod this is so useful!!! Thank u bro! I started a profiler and even If I don't use nothing there are a lot of change detection, do you have some advice to understand better how to use it?

Comment: @JanMod I've a lot of ngIf that affect my application, but I think that I haven't alternative to ngIf, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem there was a trigger ngIf at the app-component.
When the trigger of the ngIf is called in the app-component all the child-component make triggered and there was a lot of events called causing high cpu usage.

The tool adviced by @JanMod was really helpful for the understanding the name is "Angular dev tools"